# Unfinished download

Tags: ftp, wget

I have tried downloading index at ftp server from 1998 to the end of 2016

[files](ftp://igs.bkg.bund.de/IGS/obs/)

```
wget -r ftp://igs.bkg.bund.de/IGS/obs/2009/
```

I used this code than download didn't complete.
I want to resume getting downloaded file.

```
wget -c ftp://igs.bkg.bund.de/IGS/obs/2009
```

I use this code but it doesn't work.

I tried different path:

```
wget -r -nc ftp://igs.bkg.bund.de/IGS/obs/2009/
```

But I haad to do for every year.
For instance, wget -r -nc ftp://igs.bkg.bund.de/IGS/obs/2010(or 2011...)/

Answer (score 0):

The `-c` flag is needed to finish fetching any *file* if it was only partially downloaded.  You still need to use the `-r` flag to find that file, and to continue downloading the rest of the files recursively.  Therefore you should use:

```
wget -rc ftp://igs.bkg.bund.de/IGS/obs/2009/
```